# Delete link sends Get request instead of Delete Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, request

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', [task.list, task],
                        method: :delete,
                        data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Started GET "/lists/2/tasks/4" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-05-24 13:32:16 +0500

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'show' could not be found for TasksController)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @TTD said, you need to do something like this: `<%= link_to "Delete", task_path(@path), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Really?" } %> 0` 
as you need to reference just one object

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `[task.list, task],` with the path like so: `task_path(task)` (or whatever your resource path is)